# Yii CJuiSliderInput sends only one value

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I have some problem with CJuiSliderInput. I have slider price. On default CJuiSliderInput have range price 1050,2750 - when I send form the values don't send. If I change slider, only one values sends - which I changed that last.

What did I do wrong?

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiSliderInput', array(
    'name'=>'slider_range',

    'event'=>'change',
    'options'=>array(
        'values'=>array(1050,2750),// default selection
        'min'=>0, //minimum value for slider input
        'max'=>5000, // maximum value for slider input
        'animate'=>true,
        // on slider change event
        'slide'=>'js:function(event,ui){ $("#amount-range").val(ui.values[0]+\'-\'+ui.values[1]);}',
    ),
    // slider css options
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>''
    ),
));
```